# Do questions need to have a unique phrasing?

Tags: discussion, questions

The question that prompted this thought was [What adventures are there out there that would fit in this campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/742/what-adventures-are-there-out-there-that-would-fit-in-this-campaign) It's a perfectly reasonable question content-wise: the problem (if there is a problem) is that many people could repeat exactly this question (conceivably even with the same tags) and yet mean something entirely different by it.

Is this a problem that necessitates rewording of the question to something more specific, or can the SE system handle this kind of redundancy?

If it is a problem, are there any specific circumstances under which it would be OK, or is it always a bad thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think questions should have unique phrasing.  At this time, I'm not willing to say that is an absolute and there wouldn't be exceptions.

In this particular case, I think the lead to the second paragraph is much better.

> Can anyone recommend some low-level (1-4), site-based old school D&D adventures?

Modify it a bit based on the next few sentences and I'd be really happy with it.  Something like

> Can anyone recommend a low-level, site-based Cimmerian themed adventure?

"old school D&D" can be conveyed through tags or the text of the question.  I'm sure others could do a much better job of rewording it that my suggestions.

I also think that a lot of questions here could stand to have their titles reworded for clarity and exactness.  I am far from perfect, one of my questions was recently [retitled](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/3500/revisions) to make it better.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, Pat, and I agree that if the question needs to be reworded, your version is much, much better. The question I had in mind however is whether it's a general principle that such questions need a reword, or whether they are acceptable as they are.

Comment: @Dave - you are quite right.  I've reworded my answer a bit to hopefully address that.  Thanks.

Comment: You touch on a good point at the end.  If a question is really worth re-wording, someone is going to do it.  That's the way of Stack Exchange.